# Resources for understanding a programming language and its specifications and grammar deeply

Tags: programming-languages, computer-science, grammar, language-specifications

I'm a computer engineer and all the courses we have had about programming and computer languages were an introduction to C/Java and OOP. Now I feel like reading Java language specification to learn a deep understanding on Java language but I understand that there are something like grammar description in the specifications which I have no idea about. What should I study to be able to understand a programming language deeply(Especially specification elements such as grammar)? Have I missed some computer science courses? or I should understand all intuitively?

I was pondering about reading some books about compilers but I thought it'd be better asking it from the experts!

Comment: Learn BNF, it's simple and it's the most widely used way of defining language grammars. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Study a programming language as you would study a spoken language.**  Grammar is important, and you can learn that from the formal specification of the language, but grammar only goes so far.  Vocabulary matters too - actually, more.  Every programming language has its collection of "words" - Java's Base Class Library, Lisp's common functions, C's Standard Library, *etc*.  But even practice with vocabulary will only get you so far.  Every programming language also has its idioms, and being able to use those well is the mark of a native speaker.

Comment: Now I think that I don't need to read the specifications and instead of that I'd better dive in JavaEE, learn Haskell & scala and try to involve me in as many serious development projects as I can.